# Form elements are not printing?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have problem in my javascript that my form elements are not printing.I am working on front end validation. I use here document.getElementById for getting form elements but it returns empty in window elert..
Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Interns</title>


    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CompanyRegestration.css">

</head>
<body>

<div id="FormDiv">
<form>

<div id="ParagraphDiv">
    <p id="HeadingParagraph">Complete the Form for regestration</p>
    <hr id="HeadingLine">
</div>
<div id="RequiredDiv"><p id="RequiredParagraph">*Required</p></div>

<div class="DataDivs"><input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name"></div>
<div class="DataDivs"><input id="LasttName" type="text" name="LastName" placeholder="Last Name"></div>
<div class="DataDivs2"><input id="Email" type="text" name="Email"
                              placeholder="Enter your Email address (i.e     zain@gmail.com)"></div>
<div class="DataDivs"><input id="CompanyName" type="text" name="CompanyName" placeholder="CompanyName"></div>

<div class="DataDivs"><input id="Phone" type="text" name="Phone"     placeholder="Phone"></div>
<div class="DataDivs"><input id="Website" type="text" name="Website"     placeholder="Website"></div>
<div class="DataDivs"><input id="Location" type="text" name="Location" placeholder="Location"></div>
<div class="DataDivs"><input id="Password" type="password" name="Password" placeholder="Password"></div>
<div class="DataDivs"><input id="RePassword" type="password" name="RePassword" placeholder="RePassword"></div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onClick="getFormElements()">
</form>
</div>
```

**Here is javascript code:**

```
<script>
var FirstName=document.getElementById("FirstName");//it will get element by id from the form
var FirstNameValue=new String(FirstName.value);
window.alert(FirstNameValue);
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Your JS needs to be inside getFormElements()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use some Jquery with that like this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/9/

HTML

```
<div class="DataDivs"><input id="FirstName" type="text" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name"></div>
<button id="button">Check name</button>
```

JS

```
$('#button').click(function() {
var FirstName=document.getElementById("FirstName");//it will get element by id from the form
var FirstNameValue = FirstName.value;
window.alert(FirstNameValue);
});
```

**Edit**

Also for form to work you need, if you are not using ajax

```
<form action="whereYouSendData.php" method="POST">

</form>
```

Comment: I have one question for you. Can we use javascript and jquery code inside one script tag?

Answer (score 1):

You have written a javascript function on click of submit in input element,
But not written inside script tags,
So this will work;

```js
<script>
function getFormElements(){
 var FirstName=document.getElementById("FirstName");//it will get element by id from the form
 var FirstNameValue=new String(FirstName.value);
 window.alert(FirstNameValue);
}
</script>
```

`<script>
function getFormElements(){
    var FirstName=document.getElementById("FirstName");//it will get element by id from the form
    var FirstNameValue=new String(FirstName.value);
    window.alert(FirstNameValue);
}
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it right... But there is no event handler you are using.

For example if I use `'blur'` event handler on First Name then when the user exists the field the event will fire and your code will get executed.

There are 2 ways of doing it in your cast:

**One:**

Change the First Name input tag to.

```
<input id="FirstName" type="text" onblur="show_first_name();" name="FirstName" placeholder="First Name">
```

And change the script:

```
function show_first_name() {
    var FirstName=document.getElementById("FirstName");
    var FirstNameValue=FirstName.value();
    window.alert(FirstNameValue);
}
```

**Two:**

Leave your First Name field as it is.

Change the Script:

```
document.getElementById('FirstName').onblur = function() {
    var FirstName = this;
    var FirstNameValue = this.value();
    window.alert(FirstNameValue);
}
```

Hope this helps.